# Не читает вторую строку txt документа, не открывает сайт. webview выдает ошибку

Tags: python, webview

Если не указывать строку, открывает сайт, который записан в первой строке.
dex.readline(любая другая строка) выдает ошибку 500.
в dex.txt записаны только сайты.
Что нужно сделать, чтобы открывались остальные сайты.

```
import webview

# Открываем текстовый файл
dex = open('C:/Users/user/Desktop/dex.txt','r')
# Читает только первую строку
dex.readline()
# Закрывает текстовый документ после чтения
dex.close

# Open website
webview.create_window(
'Сайт', ('\n'.join(dex))
```

Comment: можно здесь почитать: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: что такое ``dex.readline(любая другая строка)``? Почему ты не читал справку по функции readline()?

Comment: читал, смысл в том, что webview не открывает сайт во второй строке.

Comment: почему ты читал справку по фунции readline()? С чего ты взял, что 2 означает номер строки?

Comment: @Эникейщик dex.readline(любая другая строка) значение 2 указываешь и webview открывет сайт с ошибкой, не правильно считываю строки.

Comment: @Эникейщик в документации прочитал readline() читает по строкам. Если нет значение выводит 0 строку.

Comment: Так надо было читать не про "если нет значения", а про "если есть значение". Если есть значение, то что происходит? И почему вдруг 0? В файлах нет нулевой строки

Comment: @Эникейщик в текстовом документе 2 строки.
Допустим как пример
1 яндекс
2 гугл 
Если readline() без значения, открывается страница яндекса, а если readline(1) вылезает ошибка 500.
Не могу понять почему так происходит

Comment: чтобы понять, нужно прочитать наконец что же означает числовой параметр в readline(). Например, в ответе на тот вопрос, на который ссылка в плашке "На этот вопрос уже дан ответ здесь".

Comment: Я разобрался, вот что я изменил.
dex = open('C:/Users/user/Desktop/dex.txt','r')
# Читает только первую строку
dexi = dex.readlines()
# Закрывает текстовый документ после чтения
dex.close

# Open website
webview.create_window(
    'Тёплый контакт', (''.join(dexi[1])),